# Bijective bounded linear operator on $\ell^q$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $1\leq p < \infty$ and suppose $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$.
> Let $b=(b_k)_k \in \ell^q$.  Define $F_b: \ell^p \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
> by $$F_b (a) = \sum_k a_k b_k, \quad a\in\ell^p.$$ Then $F: \ell^q\rightarrow (\ell^p)'$, $b \mapsto F_b$ is a bijective bounded linear
> operator.

I have already shown that $F_b$ is an element of $(\ell^p)'$ (the dual space of $\ell^p$) and that $||F_b|| = ||b||_{\ell^q}$. But I am struggling specifically to show that $F$ is bijective; if I am understanding correctly, this operator is given by something like $$F=\sum_k b_k$$

Then I would proceed with showing injectivity by supposing that $b, c\in\ell^q$ and assuming that $F_b=F_c$. But then how can I show that $\sum_k b_k= \sum_k c_k$ implies that the sequences are equal, i.e. $b_k=c_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$? Wouldn't this not be true in general?

Comment: Just evaluate $F_b$ at $e_1,e_2,...$ to show that it is injective.

Comment: You have shown injectivity. It follows from $\|F_b\|=\|b\|_q.$ If $F_b=0$ then $b=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc do you want to post that as an answer?